# Adicionar e remover porcentagem

Tags: java, matemática

Em uma certa tela eu pego um valor e adiciono 10% em cima desse valor.

```
100,00 + 10% = 110,00
```

Eu salvo o valor final (110,00). Estou com dificuldade na hora de pegar o valor final (110,00) e tirar os 10%. 110,00 - 10% = 99,00 e na real eu queria retornar aos 100,00.

Eu encontrei a seguinte formula em java, porém está dando errado em alguns casos, como 220,00

```
Double ofertaNormal = proposta.getOferta() / (1+(10.0/100));
ofertaNormal = (double) Math.round(ofertaNormal);
```

Comment: meu... 10% de 110 é 11 e não 10...

Answer (score 3):

10% de 110 dá 11, então o resultado está correto. Para obter 100, a pergunta é "que valor dá 110 quando se adiciona 10%?" Ou seja:

```
1.1x = 110
```

Logo:

```
x = 110 / 1.1
x = 100
```

---

**Edit:** Seu código Java parece correto. Se você está tendo problemas com números quebrados, é por causa de um problema inerente de precisão com `Double` (veja aqui uma explicação; a pergunta é sobre JavaScript, mas o problema é o mesmo em Java com Double e Float). Neste caso acredito que você possa usar `BigDecimal` em vez de `Double`.

Comment: A de 220,00 está correta, mas com números quebrados, por exemplo 4,02 ele está dando errado

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou dar uma olhada